# How to put child inside of the Container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Container(), how do I input child inside of the container?

```
Container(
   child: _controller.value.initialized
           ? AspectRatio(
         aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
 )
 height: globals.screenHeight * 0.25,
),
Container(
   ....
)
```

the error i get is

[image]

Comment: which container, there are 2? Also, you're missing the implementation of the ternary operator.

Comment: Better learn about dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Container(
   child: _controller.value.initialized
           ? AspectRatio(
         aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
 ):Container(),
 height: globals.screenHeight * 0.25,
),
```

The reason is that you were not correctly mentioning the false part of the condition. i.e. for that you need to put ':' and then the widget you wanna show when controller is not inititalised.